# Polar representation of convex sets

Tags: convex-analysis, polar-coordinates

Consider a set $G$ of the form
$$G=\{ru:u\in\mathbb S^{d-1}, 0\leq r\leq \phi(u)\},$$
Where $\mathbb S^{d-1}$ is the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^d$ and $\phi:\mathbb S^{d-1}\to [0,\infty)$ is a given function. Is it true that if $G$ is convex, then $\phi$ needs to be Lipschitz ?

Thank you !

Comment: $k$-Lipschitz with which constant $k$ ? $k=1$ ?

Comment: $k$-Lipschitz with some $k$.

Comment: Idea: If $G$ is convex then locally at every point $\phi$ is convex, which implies Lipschitz.

Comment: Jose27, what does it mean to be convex for $\phi$, when it is only defined on the sphere ?

Comment: You should sarch the web with the term "support function" which gives you access to a rather vast amount of litterature, for example the very accessible article "Support Function Representation of Convex Bodies, Its Application in Geometric Computing, and Some Related Representations" by Pijush K. Ghosh and K. Vinod Kumar (Comp. Vision and Image Understanding Vol 72, no 3, 1998)

Comment: Thank you Jean Marie, I will check that reference ! The support function of a bounded convex set is $k$-Lipschitz, where $k$ is the radius of a centered Euclidean ball containing $G$. Here, I think it is not straightforward to relate $\phi$ to the support function of $G$ but I will look at other representations, as indicates the title of your citation.

Comment: Little hint for this site: In order to direct a comment to somebody, you have to write an arrobas symbol just before his/her pseudo. Otherwise, he/she will not be warned.

Answer (score 2):

In general no, take $G=[-1, 1]$ and $d=2$ then function $\phi$ is neither continuous. If $0$ isn't an interior point you can consider on $\mathbb R^2$ the closed square $G$ with vertices $(0, 1)$, $(2, 1)$, $(2, -1)$ and $(0, -1)$ and $\phi$ isn't continuous on $\mathbb S^1$.

You need to suppose also that $G$ is bounded and $0$ is an interior point of $G$, so exist $M, r>0$ such that $B_r\subseteq G\subseteq B_M$ so the function $v:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow [0, +\infty[$ such that $v(0)=0$ and for every $x\neq 0$
$$
v(x)=\min\left\{t>0:\frac{x}{t}\in G\right\}
$$
that's well defined due to $B_r\subseteq G$.

Observe that $v(x)\geq \frac{\lVert x\rVert}{M}$ for every $x$ and $v(kx)=kv(x)$ for every $k\geq 0$. We prove now that $v$ is convex, let $x, y\in\mathbb{R}^d\setminus\{0\}$ such that $v(x)=a, v(y)=b$ and $\lambda\in [0, 1]$.
$$
\frac{\lambda x +(1-\lambda)y}{\lambda a +(1-\lambda)b}=\frac{\lambda x}{\lambda a +(1-\lambda)b}+\frac{(1-\lambda)y}{\lambda a +(1-\lambda)b}=\frac{\lambda a}{\lambda a +(1-\lambda)b}\frac{x}{a}+\frac{(1-\lambda)b}{\lambda a +(1-\lambda)b}\frac{y}{b}\in G
$$
because $\frac xa, \frac yb\in G$ by definition, so
$$
v\left[\lambda x +(1-\lambda)y\right]\leq\lambda a +(1-\lambda)b=\lambda v(x) +(1-\lambda)v(y)
$$

Then exists $L>0$ such that for every $x, y\in\mathbb S^{d-1}$
$$
\lvert v(x)-v(y)\rvert\leq L\lVert x-y\rVert
$$

Observe that if $x\in\mathbb S^{n-1}$ then $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{v(x)}$ so we can conclude with

$$
\lvert \phi(x)-\phi(y)\rvert=\frac{\lvert v(x)-v(y)\rvert}{v(x)v(y)}\leq LM^2\lVert x-y\rVert
$$